# Flutter released app shows app keeps stopping

Tags: android, flutter

I built an app bundle of my app and released it on Play Store. But when I install the app and run it it stops immediately saying
example_app(app name) keeps stopping.
I'm fetching data in api calls in the app. I have also added necessary permissions such as
 permission on the AndroidManifest file.
I can't find the solution of this and don't know why this is happening.

my flutter doctor -v[image]

I've used flutter build appbundle to build my bundle
app is releases on playstore but when someone opens it doesn't start and says example_app(app name) keeps stopping

I don't know what to do now

Note: I am developing in vscode

Comment: Is the released APK version works?

Comment: Your flutter channel and version are unknown as you can see from flutter doctor result. It's stragne and it could be a reason. Try to run `flutter upgrade`.

Comment: @MostafaSoliman no the released version doesn't work and google also sent me a crash report about java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

i see something wierd with your flutter version that it's showing flutter channel(unknown).
try to update flutter sdk by running the following:

- flutter upgrade
  and change to the stable channel by running:
- flutter channel stable

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. First of all I removed my flutter sdk then set it up again. Then I created a new project and copied the files inside lib of my previous project.
As far as I think the main issue was the package name, I changed my package name in AndroidManiFest.xml file under **android\app\src\main** (also changed it the AndroidManifest.xml in debug file for development **android\app\src\debug** ).
Next change the package name in build.gradle **android\app** and also set the minsdk to 21.
And lastly also need the change the package name under MainActivity.kt **android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\example\app_name**. Then everything worked

**Note: I also Built apk this time not appbundle**